# How do I seed a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to seed my `Products` and assign them to a specific `User` and `Store`.

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store

  def product_store=(id)
    self.store_id = id
  end
end
```

Note: `Store` belongs_to `Business` (`:business_name`)

**Seed.rb**

This is my basic setup:

```
user = User.create(:username => 'user', :email => 'user2@email.com') 
store = Store.create(:business_name => 'store', :address => 'Japan')
```

---

I attempted these but they did not work:

```
# This gives random ID's ranging from 1 to 4425!?
user.products.create([{:name => "Apple", :product_store => Store.find_by_address('San Francisco, USA')}])

# This gives me undefined method 'walmart'.
 user.store.products.create([ {:name => "Apple"} ])
```

Is there a way to set the ID's so I can associate my `Products` to a `Store` and `User`?

---

**UPDATE -**

I have tried the answers below and still came out unsuccessful. Does anyone know of another way to do this?

Comment: You assigned an instance of a class Store to an integer value of store_id .. :product_store => Store.find_by_address('San Francisco, USA'). This would not work.. you should be able to use Store.find_by_address('Japan').id instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was update the particular products to a certain user, see this question:

[Can I update all of my products to a specific user when seeding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787640/can-i-update-all-of-my-products-to-a-specific-user-when-seeding)

Answer (score 8):

Although it sounds like you found a workaround, the solution may be of interested to others.

**From your original seeds.rb**

```
user = User.create(:username => 'user', :email => 'user2@email.com')
store = Store.create(:business_name => 'store', :address => 'Japan')
```

**Create the store**

```
Store.create({
  user_id: user.id
  store_id: store.id
}, without_protection: true)
```

In the original code snipped "user" and "store" variables are declared. The code assigns user_id / store_id (the model columns inferred by the belongs_to relationship in the Store model) to the id values that are present in the "user" and "store" variables.

"without_protection: true" turns off bulk assignment protection on the id fields. This is perfectly acceptable in a seeds file but should be used with extreme caution when dealing with user provided data.

Answer (score 3):

Or alternatively create your stores.

Then extract the correct one
e.g.

```
store = Store.find_by_business_name('Test Store')
```

and then create it based on that
e.g.

```
store.products.create(:product_name => "Product Test", :price => '985.93')
```

This will then set the relationship id for you,

Comment: I had to change up my entire question. I added more clarity for my scenario. Thank you so far for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you're just trying to do this.

```
user = User.create(:username => 'usertwo', :email => 'user2@email.com') 
walmart = Store.create(:business_name => 'Walmart', :address => 'San Francisco, USA')

user.products.create(:name => 'Apple', :store => walmart)
```

Anything else required here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I like to consider my id's as internal to the database. It is the responsibility of the objects to perform object to object assignment.

Comment: When I put `:store => walmart` nothing gets created. When I try `:product_store => walmart` it does the same thing as my 2nd try does.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
store_1 = Store.new(:business_name => 'Test Store',
:address => 'Test Address',
:phone_number => '555-555-555')

store_1.id = 1
store_1.save!
```

The trick is not to set the id within the hash as it is protected.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a series of insert satements for this "seed migration", including the record Id  for each user, store, product etc. You might have to update database sequences after this approach.

Another approach
Create the initial records in you Rails app, through the GUI / web.
Then use something like Yaml-db. So you can dump the data to a yaml file. You can now edit that file (if necessary) and use that same file to seed another instance of the db with "rake db:load"

Either way.... You know the Ids will not be shifting around on you when these objects are created in the new db instance.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this... Probably better ones, even.
Here is a link to a write-up I did a while back for using yaml_db to seed an oracle database 
http://davidbharrison.com/database_seeding_oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.destroy_all
Product.destroy_all

user = User.create!([{:username => 'usertwo', :email =>'user2@email.com'},
{:username => 'userthree', :email => user3@email.com}])

user.each_with_index do |obj, index|
  Product.create!([{ :product_name => 'product #{index}', :user_id => obj.id }])
end
```

The table would look like this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I prefer to seed an association in rails 6

```rb
@teacher = Teacher.new(name: "John")
@student = @teacher.build_student(name: "Chris")

@teacher.save!
@student.save!
```