# Can I update all of my products to a specific user when seeding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I update all of products to assign a certain user to them?

```
admin = User.create(:name => "Admin", :password => "password")

walmart = Store.create(:name => 'Walmart', :address => 'San Francisco, Palo Alto')

walmartprices = walmart.products.create
([
  {:name => "Rice",    :price => '5.93'},
  {:name => "Chicken", :price => "2.24"},      
  {:name => "Milk",    :price => '3.81'},
  {:name => 'Eggs',    :price => '2.78'}
])

walmartprices.update_attribute(:user => admin)
```

Of course this gives me an error:

```
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<Array:0x5342f70>
```

Is this possible? How can it be done?

---

EDIT

These are my associations:

```
Product
 belongs_to :user and :store

Store
 has_many :products

User
  has_many :products
```

Comment: By the looks of things `walmartprices` will be an array the `walmart.products.create` method accepts an array of hashes.

I cant tell how the user fits in here, how is user associated?

Comment: @Bangline Its associated to the Products.

Comment: I take you used mr_x method then.. or
    walmartprices = walmart.products.create
    ([
      {:name => "Rice",    :price => '5.93', :user => admin},
      {:name => "Chicken", :price => "2.24", :user => admin},      
      {:name => "Milk",    :price => '3.81', :user => admin},
      {:name => 'Eggs',    :price => '2.78', :user => admin}
    ])

Comment: @Bangline Yes, I ended up using his, thank you though.

Comment: it is also possible to do this : `walmartprices = walmart.products.create ([ {:name => "Rice", :price => '5.93'}, {:name => "Chicken", :price => "2.24"}, {:name => "Milk", :price => '3.81'}, {:name => 'Eggs', :price => '2.78'} ].map!{|p| p.merge!(user: admin) })` so you hit the db only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one naive way to do this is :

```
walmartprices.each{|record| record.update_attribute(user: admin) }
```

for better performance, use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) :

```
Product.where( id: walmartprices.map(&:id) ).update_all( user: admin )
```